# Stretch to fit background in CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to stretch an image to fit the ENTIRE background, so far I have tried this code but it just repeats vertically which I don't want.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    background-image: url(/images/bg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
background-image: url("/images/bg.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
```

which can be abbreviated to

```
background: url("/images/bg.jpg") no-repeat fixed center;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Needed to add body height = 100%/100vh

Comment: Nice! Although it's worth noting what I have posted is (I believe) the standard way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, also back sure to enclose your path in quotes `''`:

`background-repeat: no-repeat`

For future reference, you can combine most of the background properties like so:

Model:

```
background: <background-color> | <background-image> | <background-repeat> | <background-attachment> | <background-position>
```

Your CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    background: url('/images/bg.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;
}
```

More info: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3868361